# How to execute SQL procedure with parameters using SqlAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have the following front-end code:

```
public void loadGrid()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SP_GET_STUDENT_DTLS";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROLL_NUM", DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STD_ID", DBNull.Value);
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(dt);
        GvStudentdtls.DataSource = dt;
        GvStudentdtls.DataBind();

    }
```

Below is the back-end procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_STUDENT_DTLS] @ROLL_NUM VARCHAR(20),@STD_ID INT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    IF(@ROLL_NUM IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_MSTR_STUDENT_DTLS WHERE StdId=@STD_ID AND Status=1
    END
    ELSE IF(@STD_ID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_MSTR_STUDENT_DTLS WHERE RollNo=@ROLL_NUM AND Status=1
    END
    ELSE IF(@ROLL_NUM IS NULL AND @STD_ID IS NULL)       
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_MSTR_STUDENT_DTLS WHERE Status=1 ORDER BY StdId DESC
    END     
  END
```

When I run this code, the DataTable is empty, although there is no exception thrown. What's going wrong?

Comment: Are there any records in `dbo.TBL_MSTR_STUDENT_DTLS` where `StdId` is NULL? Based on your code you're going to meet the condition `IF(@ROLL_NUM IS NULL)` since you are giving the param a `DBNull.Value` value in your front-end code...so your query will be `SELECT * FROM dbo.TBL_MSTR_STUDENT_DTLS WHERE StdId=@STD_ID AND Status=1` and in this case you're also giving the `@STD_ID` parameter a value of NULL (`DBNull.Value`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to be supplying any parameter values:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROLL_NUM", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STD_ID", DBNull.Value);
```

Insted of `DBNull.Value`, you should be putting your actual parameter values.

EDIT:
Also, your stored proc has issues. The code below:

```
IF(@ROLL_NUM IS NULL AND @STD_ID IS NULL)
```

should be your first if choice in your if/else sequence. Otherwise it will never be executed.

If both are null, the very first select will be executed, which likely won't return anything since you'll be looking for rows with StdId=null, an invalid test.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure doesn't return anything.
All `SP_GET_STUDENT_DTLS` does is printing the select result into the console.

Answer (score 0):

If indeed you are allowing the int to be null in your database, which has already been asked, then you should be passing in the parameter as [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlint32.null%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

More on Handling Null values...
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)